# Врач или доктор?

Tags: лексика

Вопрос пришел в голову не мне - был подсмотрен на одном из сообществ. Но меня он тоже заинтересовал: почему, когда мы говорим о человеке в третьем лице, мы чаще говорим "врач", а, когда обращаемся лично, то всегда - "доктор"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Утверждать не берусь, но, видимо, когда мы говорим о человеке в третьем лице, нам важно подчеркнуть только его профессиональную принадлежность. Поэтому мы используем слово **ВРАЧ** (единственное значение - 'специалист с высшим медицинским образованием, занимающийся лечебно-профилактической деятельностью'). У слова **ДОКТОР** (а оно иноязычное: < лат. doctor 'учитель, преподаватель' < docere 'учить') значений больше: 1) доктор наук -- высшая ученая степень, присуждаемая лицам, имеющим, как правило, степень кандидата наук и публично защитившим докторскую диссертацию, напр.: *доктор технических наук*; 2) в других странах -- одна из ученых степеней (условия присуждения ее различны в разных странах); 3)(разг.) = врач. Использование слова ДОКТОР при обращении к врачу, как мне кажется, - это своеобразная формула вежливости. Кстати, например, в Италии обращение dottore используется не только по отношению к врачу (medico), но зачастую и к любому человеку, окончившему университет.

Answer (score 2):

Есть версия, что называть врача доктором повелось ещё с тех времён, когда все врачи обязаны были быть Докторами, то есть получить учёную степень в области медицины. Иначе они не имели права самостоятельно лечить людей(вроде нынешней лицензии). Современным врачам, безусловно, льстит такое уважительное к ним обращение.

Answer (score 1):

Врач - слово старинное, однокоренное с "врать". Вряд ли кому будет приятно, если его в глаза вруном назовут. Да и потом такое обращение предполагает, что речь идёт именно о враче, не о каком-нибудь санитаре и даже не адъюнкте. А "доктор" таких затруднений не вызывает.
Вообще обращения по профессии - это особая статья. 
Например разница между водителем и шофёром подмечена ещё достославным героем Утесова, гордо называвшим себя "водителем кобылы".

Comment: Врач - слово старинное, однокоренное с "врать". 
Ну, раньше-то "врать" не имело негативного оттенка, означало просто "говорить, произносить заговоры".

Answer (score 0):

Безусловно - льстит! :-)

Это не это формула вежливости. Это формула страха перед неизвестностью. Всё, что связано с жизнью и смертью, всегда подвергается в языке сильной эвфемизации или табуированию.

Например, в Америке (судя по фильмам) к полицейскому сержанту (и даже рядовому) обращаются *офицер*. Тоже, скорее всего, от страха перед оружием. Ведь полицейского там вполне можно называть, например,  constable или  policeman. Но мы постоянно слышим от переводчиков именно подобострастное *офицер*...

Comment: Именно так. Даже в третьем лице их часто называют так же: police officer. (и я знаю не из фильмов...)