# Врач и доктор: есть ли разница?

Tags: значение-слов

Когда говорят о человеке медицинской профессии, часто можно услышать "доктор такой-то", но при этом мы говорим, что "идем к врачу". Таким образом, возникает вопросы: а в чем, собственно, разница между понятиями "врач" и "доктор"?
Если говорить о моем мнении, то "врач" - это просто обозначение профессии, а вот "доктор" - понятие более общее, применимое к людям, которые лечат других людей (хотя, с другой стороны, в чем разница?). Я сейчас не говорю о докторах наук, а именно о докторах, которые врачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос уже обсуждался: [Врач или доктор?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

Также: http://otvet.mail.ru/question/68718623